# IE Duplicates input fields when enter-key is pushed

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, click

I have a the following code

**HTML**

```
<button id="add-input">add</button>
<div id="input-container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#add-input').on('click',function () {
    $('<input type="text">').appendTo('#input-container');
});
```

When I click on the button with id add-input, everything works as expected. A new `<input>` element is appended to the `<div>`
However if I focus on the newly appended `<input>` and press enter on my keyboard the click event is fired again. This only happens using IE(9). I have tested it in Chrome & Firefox and they both work as expected.

jsfiddle to verify this: http://jsfiddle.net/nMhMd/

Thanks!

Comment: Try it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/CalvinAllen/nMhMd/1/

Comment: This does not help. The result is same as mentioned in the original problem, works in Chrome but  not in IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer believes your `<button>` element is a submit button. To change the behaviour, add `type="button"` to make it think it is a normal one.

```
<button id="add-input" type="button">add</button>
```